# Download a file with cURL

Tags: php, redirect, curl, server

I am trying to download a file with cURL. I have received an URL where the file is located, but the url makes an redirect before reaching the file. For some reason I always receive the logout page when I access the URL with cURL, but when I enter the URL directly in my browser the file just downloads as it is supposed to. The file that should be downloaded is a RAR file, but instead of the file I get the incorrect login page.

This the current code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

As you can see I am using the following code to allow the redirects:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

But I always receive the incorrect login page from the website if I use the above code. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here ?

This is the reponse I get from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 15:33:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=session_id; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: /nl/nl/export/download/t/Mg==/c/MTQ=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Does the URL to download the file require logging in? If so you may need to  simulate the login by using cookies in cURL.

Comment: See this response : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977535/how-do-i-download-a-file-from-an-ashx-page-with-php/34978954#34978954

Comment: @slbteam08 Yes it does need a login, but the login credentials are passed in the url. So I dont know if I have to send them next to the url.

Comment: Maybe you need to use tools like Inspect in Chrome to examine if there are any special headers / post data sent. To ensure you can download successfully, you'd better send EXACTLY the same HTTP request using cURL.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code

```
$url = "www.abc.com/xyz";//your url will come here
$fp = fopen ('test.txt', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: If I use this code, then again I receive the page that says you are not logged in.

Comment: What Url you are using ? Also try with another url, May be you are trying to access restricted url.

Comment: https://www.tyre24.com/nl/nl/user/login/userid/{userId}/password/{password}/page/L2V4cG9ydC9kb3dubG9hZC90L01nPT0vYy9NVFE9Lw==

Comment: If you hit this url with all value provided at browser, what response you are getting.

Comment: See my post, I edited it with the response header I receive from the server.