# PHP CURL Login and Download file code not working

Tags: php, csv, curl, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to login to a website and download a csv file, the login seems working but csv file is not downloading, when i do those manually i can download that file without any problem. it doesn't give any error messages and the var_dump output shows "true"

can anyone help me to fox this, thank you

```
define( 'LOGINURL', 'http://www.highlite.nl/user/login' );
define( 'LOGINFIELDS', 'Login=xxxxxx&Password=xxxx&LoginButton=LoginButton' );
define( 'DWNLDURL', 'http://www.highlite.nl/silver.download/download/products_v2_0.csv' );
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$fp = fopen("/tmp/import.csv", "w");                  

/* STEP 2. visit the login page to authenticate and set the cookie properly */
$ch = curl_init( LOGINURL );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, LOGINFIELDS );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec( $ch );

/* STEP 3. request download */
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,DWNLDURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ch);
$result = curl_exec( $ch ); 

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998100/download-a-file-with-curl/34998285#34998285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `'w+'` to your fopen function

would be ..

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/import.csv", "w+");
```

On success, the fopen function will return a file pointer resource. Note that we pass in “w+” as the second parameter because “w+” tells PHP that we want to open the file for reading and writing.

After we’ve successfully set up our file pointer, we can hand it over to cURL via the CURLOPT_FILE option, like so what you are already doing.

```
//Pass our file handle to cURL.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this

```
define( 'LOGINURL', 'http://www.highlite.nl/user/login' );
define( 'LOGINFIELDS', 'Login=xxxxxx&Password=xxxx&LoginButton=LoginButton' );
define( 'DWNLDURL', 'http://www.highlite.nl/silver.download/download/products_v2_0.csv' );
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$fp = fopen("/tmp/import.csv", "w+"); // Changed w to w+                  

/* STEP 2. visit the login page to authenticate and set the cookie properly */
$ch = curl_init( LOGINURL );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, LOGINFIELDS );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec( $ch );

/* STEP 3. request download */ /*Updated code*/
$ch = curl_init(DWNLDURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$result = curl_exec( $ch ); 
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
var_dump($result);
```